# Unable to break Business Goal table on the basis of "Year", "Month" and "Quarterly"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to break the Business Goal table using "Year", "Month" and "Quarterly" based on the Period column of BusinessGoal table. I have a Generate_Dates function which breaks the dates in yearly format and need to add the "Yearly" and "Quarterly" part.

```
;WITH Generate_Dates(Start_Date, End_Date) AS (
  SELECT
    CAST(StartDateUtc AS Date),
    CAST(
      CASE WHEN [bg].EndDateUtc IS NULL THEN GETDATE() ELSE CAST([bg].EndDateUtc AS Date) end AS Date
    )
  FROM
    BusinessGoal AS [bg] WITH (NOLOCK)
  WHERE
    [bg].Period = 'Year'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    DATEADD(yy, 1, Start_Date),
    End_Date
  FROM
    Generate_Dates
  WHERE
    DATEADD(yy, 1, Start_Date) < End_Date
)
SELECT * FROM Generate_Dates
```

The data below has two tables in which the first is the input table and the second is the output table.
[image: Data Screenshot]

Comment: What is your question here? You've told us what you "need" but not asked us anything, or told us why what you've tried didn't work. What does that image have to do with anything?

Comment: @Larnu i need to break the table into monthly, quarterly and yearly and the example screenshot is attached below.

Comment: But what is your question? "I need" isn't a question, it's a demand. If you need to do something, why are you doing it? What have you tried to solve the problem, and why didn't it work? What is your expected results here, and what's the logic behind it? (<-- These are all examples of a question.) Images of data don't help us help you; if you're going to supply data do so as tabular formatted `text` or as DDL and DML statements.

Answer (score 0):

Without more Table Data or an actual question it's hard to assume what you need but, as a prediction: 
Why not have 3-4 Unions with your Period Column as each condition. It looks like you have everything all together in one table. So, this should work as long as Columns A-G are static (which it seems like it is)

As:

```
select..."your columns"
from Generate_Dates
where period = 'Year'
union
select..."your columns"
from Generate_Dates
where period = 'Quarterly'
union
select..."your columns"
from Generate_Dates
where period = 'Monthly'
```

So it can build the rows dynamically. Then, order as needed or use Excel Formulas to handle the rest. Plus you can add more conditions to my example on each Union. This is just a rough template.